# How to make this type of expansion tile in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

here is the example image of i need

[image: Example Image]

and here is the code i tried

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, left: 30, bottom: 20),
      child: Container(
        decoration: boxDecoration,
        child: const ExpansionTile(
          collapsedIconColor: Colors.white,
          iconColor: Colors.white,
          tilePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 20, top: 5, bottom: 5),
          leading: NotifyIcon(
            size: 20,
          ),
          title: Text('Title'),
          subtitle: Text('09:15 AM'),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

here is the output i get

[image: My Output]

but there is no option to add a text above the title in expansion tile. like the example image i given. how do i achieve that?

trying to get accurate output from an example image, i tried to code and all those code and output given in this question

Comment: Looks like ListTile widget.

Comment: Since 'title' is a Widget what's stopping you from using a 'Column' for the title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code hope its helpful to you. Just change my Icon to your icon and other data also on your need apply your box decoration instead on my

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 30, left: 30, bottom: 20),
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
      border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
    ),
    child: ExpansionTile(
      collapsedIconColor: Colors.white,
      iconColor: Colors.white,
      tilePadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 20, top: 5, bottom: 5),
      leading: Icon(Icons.edit),
      title: Text(
        'Quick Reminder',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12,
        ),
      ),
      subtitle: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Text(
            'Push The Code on Main Branch',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 5,
          ),
          Text(
            '10/02/22',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 12,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Result-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

solution 1: use column widget in subtitle property instead of Text widget
Solution 2 : use ListTile widget instead of ExpansionTile in LIstTile widget has isThreeLine proprty simpley enable this